# Android App Login MS SQL

Tags: android, sql-server, json, authentication

I am trying to make an android app that requires a user to login against a MS SQL Database.

Having read around the most popular way seems to be to use JSON to do this however I'm not sure how secure this would be (especially if there is no SSL being used).

My question is what are the alternatives available and if JSON is the best/easiest way to achieve this how can I make it more secure? Is this also how big companies (such as dropbox etc) do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first started Android programming I was told that making a direct connection to the database is considered bad practice, and that an interface (JSP, PHP, .NET) should always be used. I don't know if this is a security thing or not but it would probably be the best for you.

If possible, create a .NET (or whatever server-side language you are comfortable with; .NET would probably be the easiest if you're working with a MS SQL server) page and talk to it over HTTPS (there's your security) and pass it the login info using POST. You could use JSON but name value parameters would accomplish the same thing. Have your page connect to the DB and test the information you pass it against whatever is in it. Then pass back a value that says whether it is correct or not in the response.

**EDIT:**
This looks like a decent [guide to getting HTTPS set up on Android](http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/)  (just browsed through it quickly so I can't vouch for it 100%).

Comment: Thanks for the information! I think I shall create my own .NET web service and attempt to use that! It might be a while before I actually get to setting up HTTPS though!

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just the form you pass data in.

Noone stops you from using SSL for the connection. Or encrypting the JSON data in your own  way.