# connect android to a database server

Tags: android, sql-server, database

I am new to android programming field and have read some book and tutorials over web. there are some advises here and there that say don not connect android application to ms sql server but through web service. but all of these advice are dated five or six years old. so:
1-Is this advice still true and applicable?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data locally android uses sqllite for this matter and of course if you want to access or store data outside your device you need to connect or create an api that will handle your request.

Comment: what is this api? and should i connect directly or indirectly?

Comment: Read the link https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-API-4

it's a way to connect you mobile application with your web service data

Well for android of course you need to create a web api using php , ruby, or python

Comment: see this link please , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968234/android-app-login-ms-sql it say "that an interface (JSP, PHP, .NET) should always be used" but it is a five years old question. I want to know that answer is still correct?

Comment: yes it is still correct because you can create api using JSP, PHP , .NET(C#).